# Send UWP Raw Notification from backend in C#

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, push-notification, uwp

i am trapped with a rather simple looking problem.
A little background: i am developing an App with Xamarin, a Backend in C# and use Azure as Push Notification Hub.

My goal is to send a raw notification from the backend to my UWP app via Azure notification-hub. Badge-, tile- or toast-notifications are no options in my project, so i am stuck with raw notifications.

The App is running on a Win10 machine and registers successfully with the notification-hub. Test send of notifications (either kind) from Azure works !

The backend also runs on a Win10 machine in the same network. App and backend communicate via REST (also working).

Now the Problem:
I try to send a raw notification from the backend to the Notification-Hub with the following code:

```
 var message = "Test";
 Notification notification = new WindowsNotification( message );
 notification.Headers.Add( "X-WNS-Type", @"wns/raw" );
 try
    {
      return await _notificationHub.SendNotificationAsync( notification, tag ); ;
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( $"===> Notification {message} \nTO {tag} could not be sent !!" );
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( $"{e.Message}" );
    }
```

This, i figured, should be the basic code to send a raw notification. 
But i get an exception stating:

> The content type for a 'wns/raw' notification must be 'application/octet-stream'.TrackingId:xxx,TimeStamp:8/24/2018 1:07:20 PM

So i added the line

```
notification.Headers.Add( "Content-Type", @"application/octet-stream" );
```

above the "try" - statement. 
Now i get the exception

> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

...and i have no idea how to correctly set the header.

Has anyone a helpful suggestion for me please....

THX in advance

P.S. Using VS2017 with "Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.7" and "Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 2.0.0-preview2" (just to mention the important libraries).

Answer (score 0):

> The content type for a 'wns/raw' notification must be 'application/octet-stream'

This message means that you need to sepcify the content type of a 'wns/raw' notifycation. I check the [WindowsNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.windowsnotification?view=azure-dotnet#properties) document, it has a `Notification.ContentType` property, please try to specify the value for this property.

Comment: Thank you for our reply. But unfortunately after adding `notification.ContentType = @"application/octet-stream"; ` , the exception is still present: "The content type for a 'wns/raw' notification must be 'application/octet-stream' "